# Making a comment to the DOM from a constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am trying to make function that will post comment that'll add a headline and a text-section, based on a constructor-object. #Title and #text are the two bars in which the text will go. #form is the button the event listens to. I can't seem to get it to work now. Ideas?

```
function commentPost (title, text){
this.title = $("title").val; 
this.tekst = $("text").val;

}

var commentPosts = [];

var formular = $('#form');


formular.on('click', function getTarget(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var jsTitleInput = $('title').val;
      var jsTextInput = $('text').val;
      var newComment = new commentPost(jsTitleInput, jsTextInput); 
      commentPost.push(newComment);
      console.log(newComment);
});
```

Comment: You're not using your parameters in your constructor

Comment: also the posts array is declared as commentPosts but used as commentPost, you forget a 's'

Comment: and I think that title and text are not tags name, and the .val is a function, not a property, you have to call it in this way `$('.myClass').val()`